# Change order status on Frontend Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I want to build a page on wordpress that displays the shortcode [my_plugin_order_details] that performs the functions that I have written down.
Functions include:

1. Display order code search box
2. When the administrator enters the order code and presses submit (Search), the order details will be displayed. Comes with the option to change the status.
3. Admin can change order status. After pressing submit (Update Status), print the correct status or not...
   Here is my code snippet:

```php
function my_plugin_order_details_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $output = '';

    // Check if the order code was submitted
    if ( isset( $_POST['order_code'] ) ) {
        $order_code = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['order_code'] );

        // Get the order by code
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_code );

        // If the order is found, display its details
        if ( $order ) {
            $output .= '<h2>Order Details</h2>';
            $output .= '<p><strong>Order Number:</strong> ' . $order->get_order_number() . '</p>';
            $output .= '<p><strong>Order Date:</strong> ' . date_i18n( 'j \t\h\á\n\g n \nă\m Y, g:i a', strtotime( $order->get_date_created()->date_i18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) ) ) . '</p>';
            $output .= '<p><strong>Order Total:</strong> ' . wc_price( $order->get_total() ) . '</p>';
            $output .= '<p><strong>Order Status:</strong> ' . $order->get_status() . '</p>';
        
            // Add a form to change the order status
            $output .= '<h2>Change Order Status</h2>';
            $output .= '<form method="post">';
            $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="' . $order->get_id() . '">';
            $output .= '<select name="new_status">';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-processing">Processing</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-on-hold">On Hold</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-completed">Completed</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-cancelled">Cancelled</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-refunded">Refunded</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-failed">Failed</option>';
            $output .= '<option value="wc-checkout-draft">Draft</option>';
            $output .= '</select>';
            $output .= '<input type="submit" value="Update Status">';
            $output .= '</form>';

            // Check if the new status was submitted
            if ( isset( $_POST['new_status'] ) && isset( $_POST['order_id'] ) ) {
                $new_status = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['new_status'] );
                $order_id = absint( $_POST['order_id'] );
                $note = 'Status changed manually';
                $manual = true;
                $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
            
                if ( $order ) {
                    $order->update_status( $new_status, $note, $manual );
                    $output .= '<p>Order status updated to ' . $new_status . '</p>';
                } else {
                    $output .= '<p>Failed to update order status. Invalid order ID.</p>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $output .= '<p>No order found with code ' . $order_code . '</p>';
        }
    }

    // Add the search form

    $output .= '<h2>Search Order</h2>';
    $output .= '<form method="post">';
    $output .= '<label for="order_code">Order Code:</label>';
    $output .= '<input type="text" name="order_code" id="order_code" required placeholder="'.$order_code.'">';
    $output .= '<input type="submit" value="Search">';
    $output .= '</form>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_plugin_order_details', 'my_plugin_order_details_shortcode' );
```

I don't understand why can't update order status.
When I click submit (update status) it automatically returns to the original search box.
Can anyone help me?

I want to create a page in front-end to search for order code, once found, will display order information and change status on this page. But I am stuck at the step of changing order status on woocommerce. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this i have created a working solution, it does not add a note, but should help you continue with your project

```html
  <?php
// WooCommerce database connection details
define( 'DB_NAME', 'dbname' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'dbuser' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpass' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'WC_ORDERS_TABLE', 'wp_posts' ); // change this to match your database prefix

// Connect to the database
$conn = new mysqli( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME );

// Check connection
if ( $conn->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error );
}
?>


<form method="post">
    <label for="'ID'">Order ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="order_id" id="order_id" required>
    
    <label for="new_status">New Status:</label>
    <select name="new_status" id="new_status">
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
        <option value="wc-pending">Pending Payment</option>
        <option value="wc-processing">Processing</option>
        <option value="on-hold">On Hold</option>
        <option value="cancelled">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="refunded">Refunded</option>
    </select>
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Status">
</form>


<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];
    $new_status = $_POST['new_status'];
    
    // Check if the order exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . WC_ORDERS_TABLE . " WHERE ID = $order_id";
    $result = $conn->query( $query );
    
    if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ) {
        echo 'Order not found.';
        exit;
    }
    
    // Update the order status
    $query = "UPDATE " . WC_ORDERS_TABLE . " SET post_status = '$new_status' WHERE ID = $order_id";
    
    if ( $conn->query( $query ) === TRUE ) {
        echo 'Order status updated successfully.';
    } else {
        echo 'Error updating order status: ' . $conn->error;
    }
}
?>

<?php
$conn->close();
```